# Cannot add database connection using windows authetication SQL Server and ArcSDE 10.3

Tags: arcgis-desktop, enterprise-geodatabase, sql-server, database, arcgis-10.3

We can't seem to add a database connection from ArcSDE to sql server 2008 using ArcCatalog 10.3.1 from a specific computer with a specific username. When trying to add a database connection using this specific user's login (call it myuser), we encounter the error "Failed to connect to the specified server. Do you want to continue? Bad login". This occurs even when attempting to add a database connection using database authentication, but ONLY on this specified computer AND specified login

We have been trouble shooting this for the last day not and cannot seem to find a solution

To add more complexity to the problem, other registered users can add a database connection using their windows login on this computer and myuser can add a database connection using her windows login on other computers. Other users can also add a connection at the database level with the correct crudentials

- Double checked the instance and database names for myuser
- we have tried deleting and recreating the user from the instance level in sql
- added sysadmin privileges to the user in sql server

We have tried just about everything but myuser is still unable to add a database connection on her computer.

Why is this?

Comment: Interestingly enough, when we created a new enterprise geodatabase in arccatalog and mapped each active directory user to this database in sql server, myuser was able to add a connection to both the new database and the original database in arccatalog. This has solved the problem, however the root of the initial problem still remains a mystery !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Interestingly enough, when we created a new enterprise geodatabase in arccatalog and mapped each active directory user to this database in sql server, myuser was able to add a connection to both the new database and the original database in arccatalog. This has solved the problem, however the root of the initial problem still remains a mystery !